# Why do conker flowers grow upwards?

Tags: plant-anatomy

Most trees I know that have their flowers in groups hang these groups down. I noticed, however, that conker flowers grow upwards!
I guess that growing against gravity requires special effort, so conker may benefit somehow from growing the flowers upwards. Is this true? What's the benefit?

[image]

Comment: The main and maybe the only reason for me looks to be phototropism. Also read heliotropism though I can't guess if this is a factor with regard to the conker tree.

Comment: I would think that this is a inherited morphological trait within the subfamily. And I doubt it requires additional effort.